# How to create an instance of inner generic type of an alias type with TypeTag or ClassTag?

Tags: scala, generics, reflection, nested-generics

I know how to do it with Manifest. I'm wondering how I can do it with TypeTag or ClassTag.

Just FYI, the generic type is aliased.

```
case class S()
case class M()

case class MyMultiPurposeClass[T](member: T)

type MyTypeS = MyMultiPurposeClass[S]
type MyTypeM = MyMultiPurposeClass[M]

def create[T](implicit tag: TypeTag[T], mf: Manifest[T]): T = {
    // It's this step I want to know how to do it with TypeTag or ClassTag.
    val member =
        mf.typeArguments.head.runtimeClass.getConstructors.head.newInstance()
    // But, of course, the ultimate goal of this function is to create a MyTypeS
    // or MyTypeM instance.
    ev.runtimeClass.getConstructors.head.newInstance(member)

    // Do the same thing with tag.
    ???
}

create[MyTypeS]
create[MyTypeM]
```

Comment: hmm, your TypeTag argument is implicit, i.e. it's already used to create the instance, hasn't it?

Comment: @AlexEvseenko No. I put TypeTag there only because if people copy the code they could immediately try to use it. Without the tag as a parameter, the code works.